# Run MySQL Query in Java?

Tags: java, sql, database

How do I run a MySQL Query in Java?

I saw a few examples online, but they looked strenuous. One query required 30+ lines of code, excluding connecting to the host and such.

Is there not a short, simple, easy way to run a query/fetch results from an SQL database in Java like in PHP?

Comment: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/GetRsData.html

Comment: @GrayAdams - the downvotes are for *research effort*. There are quite literally hundreds of tutorials available online that show you how to use a database with Java (JDBC). If you had a specific question about a problem you were having after trying to actually do something yourself, it would be appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site - however it is advisable to read the FAQ first.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the 30-line example? A simple query, including connection, can be done in less than that, as evidenced by Bruce's link. Without a specific issue, it's difficult to understand what problems you're actually having.

Comment: I think the question does not deserve so many negative votes. For someone coming from a language like PHP, database connections in Java may appear to be more verbose.

Comment: @Rahul They *are* more verbose--while I didn't downvote, I suspect Brian's comment regarding effort is accurate.

Comment: Here is really nice example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809239/query-a-mysql-db-using-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below example shows you to connect to database and retrieve records from the table.

```
Connection con = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  String db = "jdbctutorial";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String user = "root";
  String pass = "root";
  try{
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);`enter code here`
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  employee6");
  System.out.println("Emp_code: " + "\t" + "Emp_name: ");
  while (res.next()) {
  int i = res.getInt("Emp_code");
  String s = res.getString("Emp_name");
  System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s);
  }
  }
  catch (SQLException s){
  System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
  }  
  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
finally {
con.close();
}
```